# How to fetch data inside cdata block using nsxmlparser

Tags: objective-c

I have used nsxmlparser to fetch data from xml file.For normal file all works good but when there cdata block i am not able to handle it.
I have used this function,

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",someString);
}
```

It fetches total cdata block but i am not able to fetch tags inside the cdata block so if anybody knows solution please help me.

Is there solution is to use secondary parser to parse cdatablock if yes then please tell me the procedure to use secondary parser.
Thank you in advance